# Alternatives of fopen, fread for reading from string?

Tags: c, string, file, fread

I have a code which integrates with a certain library I cannot modify and reads from file. I need to turn it into reading from string instead of from file.

```
string str = "I now have the string from file.txt in memory";

// original code:
FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
// ...
uint8_t buffer[128];
// ...
var->var1 = buffer;
// ...
var->var2 = fread(buffer, 1, 128, file);
// ...
```

So a simple question, what's an alternative for fread for reading from string into buffer?

Platform: Windows

Comment: First please pick *one* language: Are you programming in C or C++? They are both *very* different languages. Secondly, what platform are you on? It will tell us what alternatives there are. Lastly, perhaps you should check what [the `fread` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) *actually* returns?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no big deal what it returns, I just need something to bufferize string like file can be by utilizing fread

Comment: There are no equivalent functions for reading a stream from string. If your library reads from a file using `fread`, how would an alternate function help anyway? You need to simulate the file, not replace the function

Comment: You could, of course, put the string into a file and read from there. Now, to avoid touching the disk, you can use a memory-backed file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude whoops, sorry, fixed the typo

Comment: What is the interface of your lib? Do you provide a filename, a FILE* pointer or else?

Comment: @Gerhardh all the relevant lines are above, so the library just takes uint8_t buffer and the result of fread (which is always '1')?

Comment: This depends on a platform. There are alternatives for Unix

Comment: While you picked a language you still haven't told us what platform (operating system) you're targeting. This could be solved easily on some platforms but not others. Also, as asked by @Gerhardh, what are you passing the library? Is it the library that does the `fopen` call or do you in your own code?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude platform: windows; nope fopen is not from the library, but from example of its usage. The library just takes a buffer. Basically if I replace the line with fread, everything will be great

Comment: How does it get the result from `fread`? Does it call `fread`within the lib or do you pass it somehow?

Comment: So do you need a `FILE *`, or not?  If you just want to "read from a string to a buffer", seems to me `memcpy` would do the trick.

Comment: @SteveSummit don't need it. What's an example for memcpy?

Comment: @Gintas_ See my second answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't require a `FILE *`, if you just need to copy counted characters from one buffer (or string) to another, that's what `memcpy` is for.  For example, to a first approximation, you could replace

```
fread(buffer, 1, 128, file);
```

with

```
memcpy(buffer, str, 128);
```

Now, this will break pretty badly if `str` does not contain 128 characters.  (If your `file` had less than 128 characters on it, `fread` would give you less than 128.)  So a safer replacement would be

```
int n = 128;
if(strlen(str) < n) n = strlen(str);
memcpy(buffer, str, n);
```

Comment: Is there a way to replace the length/individual size argument (in this case 1) on memcopy?

Comment: @bluejayke Just multiply.  That is, in general, the first example becomes "you could replace `fread(buffer, m, n, file)` with `memcpy(buffer, str, m*n)`".

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a function that does precisely what you want: [`fmemopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen).  You hand it a pointer to an in-memory string buffer, and a `"r"` or `"w"` flag (just like `fopen`), and it gives you a regular old `FILE *` that you can read from or write to -- or, in your case, pass to a function that needs a `FILE *` to read from or write to.

It's available in glibc and therefore in virtually all versions of Linux.  I think it's available in some versions of Unix.  I don't seem to have it on my Mac.  I'm afraid you'll probably have a hard time finding it for Windows.

Comment: `fmemopen()` was standardized by POSIX in its 2008 revision.  I would therefore expect OSX to have it, but you may need to define an appropriate feature-test macro (see its docs) to get the function declaration.  But of course, OSX is sometimes a bit surprising when it comes to standard conformance.  Note well that `fmemopen()` is not in the C standard itself.  Windows might *not* have it, however.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your task correctly, you need to get information out of a string as if they would been written from a file. A very comfortable way to solve that is [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/), if you are using C++.

Comment: The OP has clarified via his tagging that he is using C, not C++.